# My Angular app is launching on IPhone but not on IPad

Tags: ios, angular, ipad, safari

I have develop an App with Angular (not AngularJS...) but when I launch the App on Ipad it fails with the error on line `<pr-product [ngClass]="productNGClasses"></pr-product>` of my first HTMLComponent : 
**TypeError: Object.values is not a function. (In 'Object.values(pParams)', 'Object.values' is undefined**

Here is my HTML Component code :

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <pr-top-menu [ngStyle]="topMenuNGStyles" class="col-12"></pr-top-menu>
</div>
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <pr-left-menu [ngClass]="leftMenuNGClasses" [ngStyle]="leftMenuNGStyles"> 
</pr-left-menu>
    <pr-right-menu [ngClass]="rightMenuNGClasses" [ngStyle]="rightMenuNGStyles"> 
</pr-right-menu>
    <pr-product [ngClass]="productNGClasses"></pr-product>
</div>
```

This code works on Safari desktop, Chrome Desktop and all Browsers but not on safari and Chrome on Ipad

Any help ?
Thanks a lot for your help.